# Facing difficulty while fetching the value from DatePicker Button?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a button to show DatePicker. When I clicks the Button, it will show the DatePickerDialog. Here I'am trying to get date value and i want to fetch it in a TextView. But I'am facing difficulty when i try to fetch the value. How can i can print the date value in TextView?

Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
text1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
text2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
text3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
text4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
date=(Button) findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, mDateSetListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
        dpd.show();
    }
});
   final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
private void updateDisplay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textdate.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(mmonth+1).append("-").append(mday).append("-")
    .append(myear));
}
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new 
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                myear=year;
                mmonth=monthOfYear;
                mday=dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };
```

Comment: what problem you found? please ellaborate

Comment: When i click the button, it shows DatePicker dialog. But If i choose any date and if i give done then the application stopped working. It shows the error in updateDisplay() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized `textdate`.

Create a global variable `textdate` and initialize it like

```
textdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

where `text_view` is the `id` of your `TextView` like you do for your `EditText` and `Button`

Answer (score 0):

Call this on whatever your button you want to display the picker

```
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Once the picker is shown you will have ok button

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                year, month, day);
        DatePicker dp = d.getDatePicker();
        dp.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return d;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        tv1.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);

    }
}
```

On the date set method refer textview

Answer (score 0):

This Code May help you to solve your problem...

Try This...

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        pYear  = selectedYear;
        pMonth = selectedMonth;
        pDay   = selectedDay;

        // Show selected date 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        // saving date to String variable
        String formatedDate = sdf.format(new java.util.Date(pYear-1900, pMonth, pDay)); 
        // setting date to TextView


        // **Note :** Make sure that you have defined value to your textview i.e. textview must not null...
        txt_date.setText(formatedDate);

    }
};
```